# angular pip function how to create and apply it ngFor

Tags: angular

I am using Angular for get response form API

my response

```
{"Test":
[{"username":"Test","status":"D"},
{"username":"Test","status":"P"},
{"username":"Test","status":"M"]}
```

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ReportService {
  uri = 'http://localhost:3000/api/url';
  token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  myData : any;
  Object = Object;
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getBusinesses(){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'x-access-token': `${this.token}` });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get(`${this.uri}`, options)
    .subscribe(
      result => {
        this.myData = result.text();
        console.log(result.text());
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error.text());
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know how to print this i google it they are using pipe function i don't know how to create pipe function and loop it

can any one explain why pipe function for loop data

Comment: What are you getting on `console.log(result.text())`? The response mentioned above?

Comment: {"Test":
[{"username":"Test","status":"D"},
{"username":"Test","status":"P"},
{"username":"Test","status":"M"]}

Comment: Is that structure will be same always?

Comment: Yes its same .....

Comment: What version NG are you using? Http has been deprecated for quite a few versions now..

Comment: thanks @MikeOne i got a solution

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making myData as type any,

```
myData : any;
```

Make it an interface,

```
myData : {
    Test : {
        username : string,
        status   : string
    }[]
} = { Test : [] }
```

In your HTML,

```
<div *ngFor="let data of myData.Test">
    Username : {{data.username}}, Status : {{data.status}}
</div>
```

This will be display your data as,

> Username : Test, Status : D
>
> Username : Test, Status : P
>
> Username : Test, Status : m
>
> ...

Comment: How to make interfce

Comment: this is Test name it should be changed based on user

Comment: @myTest Username field or Test field? Which will vary?

Comment: You need to define a constant structure in order to use ngFor or it will cause errors.